# Xcode clang segfaults when archiving project with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook, frameworks

I am building a `Swift` project in `Xcode 7.2`, I have successfully build it for simulator (i`OS 9.2`) and for two different `iOS` devices (`iOS 9.3`) but when I try to archive my project clang segfaults.
I am nearly sure is a problem with `Facebook SDK` (latest version) because `Xcode` successfully creates the archive when I remove `Facebook` `frameworks` and all `Facebook` code related from my project.

At first there was a warning when I built for `iOS` simulator about auto linking `Bolts.framework` which is used by `FBSDKCoreKit`, I thought this was the problem, I fixed this by adding `Bolts.framework` into the `framework` directory but clang kept segfaulting.

All `Facebook frameworks` I need are properly linked by Xcode in '`Build Phases' -> 'Link Binary with Libraries`' and `'General' -> 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'`, and `'Framework Search Paths'` points to the right direction. I am exposing the frameworks to `Swift` via `Bridging Header.`

Here is the segfault:

```
Ld /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/[PROJECT NAME].build/Release-iphoneos/[PROJECT NAME].build/Objects-normal/armv7/[PROJECT NAME] normal armv7
    cd "/Users/user1/Desktop/[PROJECT NAME]"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME]-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME]-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/user1/path/to/facebook-sdks/FacebookSDKs-iOS-20160412 -filelist /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME]-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/[PROJECT NAME].build/Release-iphoneos/[PROJECT NAME].build/Objects-normal/armv7/[PROJECT NAME].LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.2 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME]-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME]-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/[PROJECT NAME].build/Release-iphoneos/[PROJECT NAME].build/Objects-normal/armv7/[PROJECT_NAME].swiftmodule -framework Bolts -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME]-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/[PROJECT NAME].build/Release-iphoneos/[PROJECT NAME].build/Objects-normal/armv7/[PROJECT NAME]_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJECT_NAME]-aghpdhmffnurkjfosupvbolgwxmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/[PROJECT NAME]/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/[PROJECT NAME].build/Release-iphoneos/[PROJECT NAME].build/Objects-normal/armv7/[PROJECT NAME]

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the latest version of `Facebook SDK` won't work when archiving project with `Xcode 7.2`. Since updating to `El Capitan` and `Xcode 7.3` was not an option for me, I had to download `Facebook SDK` previous version to make it work.